# Primefaces Datatable disabledSelection update by check

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces, datatable, updates

I need to **block** some *checkboxes* when reach the limit of **20 checkboxes** selected on my *Primefaces Datatable*, if the *checkboxes* is lower than 20 then I **unblock** the *checkboxes*

This is my code:

On my Datatable:

```
disabledSelection="#{trackingController.selectedVehicles.size() ge 20 and trackingController.checkboxChecked[vehicle.vehicleId] eq false}"

<p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>
<p:column visible="false">
    <p:outputLabel id="mapCol" styleClass="mapCol" value="#{trackingController.selectedValue(vehicle.vehicleId)}" />
</p:column>
```

On my Controller:

```
private Map<Long,Boolean> checkboxChecked = new HashMap<Long,Boolean>();

/*Some method when check*/
checkboxChecked.replace(vehicleEntity.getVehicleId(),true);

/*Some method when uncheck*/
checkboxChecked.replace(vehicleEntity.getVehicleId(),false);

/*To get the actual boolean of the check*/
public boolean selectedValue(long vehicleId){
    Boolean res = checkboxChecked.get(vehicleId);
    return res;
}
```

All of this works just fine actually:

[image]

reach to the 20 limit, then do a pagination:

[image]

The 21 value its disabled and cannot be checked **(excellent)**
But, if I **uncheck** one of the *first 20*, then *check the lonely value of the pagination* **I've got one value of my first 20 disabled** (ok):

[image]

If I uncheck other value of this first 20 values the behavior I expect its:

**The blocked checkbox now can be check, on total 2 checkboxes can be checked now**

But what I've got its that the **blocked checkbox its still blocked**:

[image]

The **disabledSelection** only works fine when do a *pagination*.
I haven't find a way of refresh the checkbox of some way to achieve the behavior I want.

If anyone have any idea of how **update** or **refresh** the *table* or *disabledSelection* I will be really grateful. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

A can try add a `p:ajax` as children of `p:dataTable` updating the table on `rowSelect`, `rowUnselect` and `toggleSelect` events:

```
<p:dataTable ...>
  <p:ajax event="rowSelect" process="@this" update="@this"/>
  <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" process="@this" update="@this"/>
  <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" process="@this" update="@this"/>
...
</p:dataTable>
```